# Effects of breaking down the oceans plastic within 5 years

Tags: science-based, environment, poisons, microorganisms, bacteria

The oceans are full of plastic. In a story about the morals of DNA changes, one scientist meaning well creates a group of super bacteria/microorganisms (afterwards just called bacteria for simplicity sake).  Once released in each of the oceanic garbage patches they eat through all available plastic in about 5 years. It can differ per patch size of course, but let's not get too bogged into these specifics. Thanks to this rapid breaking down of plastic I expect an environmental impact.

I would like the result to be overheard in the story. Breaking down so much plastic cannot be healthy for the environment. It might not spread too easily as it's often in relatively stable ocean environments, but I do expect some spread of the resulting remains.

Keep in mind that this question is not about the bacteria spreading, but just the effect of the broken down plastic.

### Research

I did some research, but could only find pop articles that mostly do not truly talk about the resulting remains of broken down plastic. I once remember reading that one of the byproducts was still toxic, but I am unable to find it. At best I found that breaking down plastic offers other toxic products, but no specifics. Even without direct toxicity I expect the huge influx of the broken down plastic will have an impact.

### Assumptions

- The scientist is a smart man, making the best choices available, but will take the step of spreading the bacteria.
- Scientist will make the bacteria with that has the least impactful method of breaking down the plastic.
- No one knows about it. They do know something is up thanks to satellite imaging seeing the patches shrink and samples of the water showing the broken down plastic, if not direct environmental impacts.
- Only the ocean garbage patches regarded as the largest are targeted.
- It isn't broken down into microplastics. It can no longer in any way be seen as a plastic.
- Unless you like looking into the slow start and increasing rapid breaking down of plastic as the bacteria spreads and grows in numbers, you can assume a linear consumption of the plastic in 5 years.

### What would the environmental impact be of breaking down the plastic in the largest garbage patches in the ocean in 5 years?

Comment: *"Breaking down so much plastic cannot be healthy for the environment":* Ummm, just how much is so much? And what is the mysterious meaning of the phrase "breaking down"? This is important because the question asks about the environmental impact of "breaking down" the plastic floating in the ocean, and the environmental impact very obviously depends on the specifics of breaking down. Moreover, taking the literal interpretation of "breaking down", that is, resolution of the polymers into the constituent monomers, the result will be almost no impact, because most plastic is poly-*ethylene*.

Comment: To answer this question you'll need to define what the least impactful method for bacteria to break down plastic in 5 years is, and more importantly what the impact of that method will be. Then impact per unit plastic * units of plastic in the ocean/5 years will be the answer to your question.

Comment: These are microorganisms, so "break down" implies digestion and release of bacteria shit into the environment.

Comment: The oceanic 'plastic patches aren't that dense.. My answer would be 'mildly elevated algae growth'. as  the increased bioavailability of nutrients would spur growth.

Comment: I agree with @sphennings. Without explaining the specific nature of the breakdown, this is a very difficult (aka, too broad) question. If your method breaks the plastic down to constituent atoms, there's possibly no problem at all. Inject those chemicals into something as large as an ocean and they'd simply merge into the whole without effect. Break it down into another hydrocarbon (one that isn't a plastic) and you might kill a substantial amount of life in the ocean. The choices are too broad, and without the choice, the consequences are even more broad.

Comment: @sphennings I am still doing research to find a method myself and will add it if I got a suitable one, but until such time I hope some knowledgeable people have a good answer.

Comment: This question is too undefined to be suitable for this site. The mechanism will affect the answer and you haven't defined any criteria for "suitable" or "least impactful" method. Each method will have asymmetric tradeoffs. How these tradeoffs are valued will affect what is determined to be suitable.

Comment: Well. That was fun! By the way, you never did point out the "slander and bigotry" in my answer. Not that there is any, but I am curious as to what you consider "slanderous" in there?

Comment: What if you have a glass-fibre boat? The glue that holds the fibres together is a sort of plastic. Would it eat that? What else might it eat?

Answer (score 6):

**Negligible**

The bacteria in question (both RL and story) feed on plastic, dismantling it into smaller compounds which vary per plastic eaten but are a lot simpler to digest by something else. And yes, these are down to CO2, CO and CH4, which are pretty much leftovers from many existing ecosystems, I even wonder if CO would actually be produced by these bacteria. And the amount of plastic eaten in 5Y is certainly less than amount of coal burned by humans in the same period.

Comment: *Very* much less than the amount of coal and petroleum burned by humans. Only about 5% of the petroleum extracted is made into plastics, and almost none of the coal. 95% of the petroleum extracted and almost 100% of the coal are burned.

Comment: There are, however, many years of plastic to be eaten. If the bacteria produce a lot of methane - which is well over 20x as impactful as CO2 in the shorter term - then you'd get a noticeable acceleration in warming.

Answer (score 2):

**The end of the world as we know it**

The scientist had good intentions. But we all know where all good intentions eventually lead - to Hell!

It would start slowly with nobody noticing a thing. The bacteria would multiply and start consuming those plastic patches. The speed of the removal of that plastic wouldn't be linear thou, it would be exponential. Firstly, bacteria grow exponently. And secondly because by partially degrading plastic you increase its surface! So more surface is exposed and it gets degraded more quickly.

So the first months almost nothing would happen. By the time someone would notice the patches shrinking it would be too late. Sooner or latter some bacteria would escape those trash-islands - and from there they would spread EVERYWHERE! Plastic is ubiquitous where people live, and we live all over the planet. Which means your bacteria would prosper there as well. Sure you say: "degradation of (most common kinds of)plastic doesn't create any toxic products!" But that is not the issue. Degradation itself is the issue!

Imagine building everything we have out of wood. Wood that you cannot put a protective coat of paint over it, as that polymere would get eaten as well. As soon as it would get a little humid in your room your computer would get infected. And not by a computer virus, but by a microorganism that would literally eat parts of it. Then packages for food would have to be remade, as plastic would be useless material for them. Depending on how thorough your scientist was we could be forced to rethink car tyres. Isolation of wires would be gone. Isolation of buildings would be gone.

Your scientist has single handedly brought civilization to its knees! The calamity would disturbe logistic chains and thus create a famine that would kill bilions. If a world war would start is a question of if countries would even be able to wage it, as everything would be in shambles.

Comment: Unfortunately I specified that my question is not about the bacteria spreading. I am purely interested in the environmental impact of the broken down impact.

Comment: In fact spreading of those bacteria won't do much to stuff that's not exposed or can be treated with antibacterial solutions. Say those bacteria would have a very hard time reaching a plastic tube buried under the ground, and even if it will, it'll have a hard time eating it, as the bacteria in question require oxygen, and underground is likely anaerobic or lacking oxygen due to other processes. However, plastic surfaces would require regular inspection and treatment against those bacteria. Several industry leaders greedily rub their hands...

Comment: I don't know, I think that degradation of plastic in our civilization  that leads to a total collapse is kinda an environmental impact... And I barely talked about how the bacteria would spread, except that it would be fast. @Vesper If we put 90% of our global industrial production into producing antibiotics we still wouldn't be able to do what you propose... Introduction of those bacteria into environment is a game over for us.

Comment: @Negdo I think you overestimate the amount of damage that bacteria eating plastic (at the must faster than reality rate) could actually cause, they eat plastic, they aren’t immortal godly bacteria.

Comment: @Negdo antibiotics are not what I meant. Antibiotics are for internal use on humans (or animals), while I was saying about applying antibacterial to external surfaces, like tubes and windows. Chlorine-based substances would do for this, while you won't be ingesting them to work as antibiotics, and making these in volumes is decently easy.

Comment: @Topcode It is more that you are underestimating how much damage they could cause. Anything made out of plastic would behave like it was made out of untreated wood at best.

Comment: @Negdo about 200 million tons of plastic are on the ocean (on the high end of estimates) and we produce well over 400 millions tons of plastic every year. So, In the timespan it takes these creatures to break down 200 million tons, humanity has made tenfold that. But you are also ignoring a crucial detail, not every plastic is identical. The best choice would be to leave some plastics that are infrequently used out of the modified organism, which means you will then be able to protect new, non single use plastics, using those plastics, that isn’t broken down.

Comment: @Topcode There is a thing called exponential growth. First 200 mil tons would take 5 years, but the second 200 mil would take 5 months. Bacteria can (and DO) multiply and eat plastic exponentaly, but we cannot expand our production even linearily. As for different types of plastics: we already use plastics with desirable properties, so those kinds are in ocean trash heaps in huge quantitites. A scientist could (and most likely would? I know that I would if I were in his place) design a bacteria to eat all those kinds. And then designing new kind of usable plastic is an issue.

Comment: “A good science fiction story should be able to predict not the automobile but the traffic jam.” ― Frederik Pohl

Comment: @Negdo "There is a thing called exponential growth" yeah, and it will stop. it wont go on forever, remember, these bacteria being created are not immortal gods, they just eat plastic better than other bacteria. They will get eaten and killed by all the stuff that eats and kills other bacteria, and wont be able to grow indefinitely. "A scientist could design a bacteria to eat all those kinds" remember, op says "making the best choices available" which doesnt include making it break down every single type of plastic invented, because that's a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of futile research of what plastics break down into, I would recommend researching what they are composed of. Because that is precisely what they will be broken down into. It is the same as any dead organic material broken down into its chemical components: carbon, hydrogen, nitrogen, etc.